# How to Flip a Video Clip

Tags: video-sequence-editor, effects, motion-capture

I want to take a video of me standing on the right side of the screen, split it, then flip the second half so I'm standing on the left side of the screen. I'm using a green screen, so I'm planning on masking out the top clip. I don't know why I can't find any tutorials on flipping a video. I can only find how to rotate videos. Another side question: how can I add a video in the video editor (which I already did), but be able to access it in the motion tracking view? I would like to cut the clips (and some other basic editing), and then do the masking (duplicating myself)/removing the greenscreen. I really appreciate any help as this is for a school project that is due tomorrow :).

Comment: If you are in the compositor, you can just scale by -1 along the x-axis.

Comment: You can first open your footage in the Movie Clip Editor and do your tracking/masking and afterwards add it to the VSE not via Add - Movie but Add - Clip. But this site works best when you don't ask many not closely related questions in one questions but split them up into multiple questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Compositor:
This can be done with the *Flip Node* within the compositor: *Add> Distort> Flip*.
The node should look like this:

[image: Flip Node]

Video-Sequence Editor:
This can be easliy don with the flip options in your *Properties Panel* `N`. The options should look like this:

[image]
For your other question I'm pretty sure you need to re-open your video, essentially your not editing the video but making a mask which can be accesed with the *Mask Node* so it doesn't really matter as long your using the same footage.